# jQuery events progressively growing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really quite confused to as what is happening here and if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be great.

The following script is set to run when I click on an item from my navigation and it will reload the content into the div titled "loadswcontent".

The issue I'm having is when this is running, over-time it begins to duplicate. Please use this screen below as reference. It's marked in segments, the first time I click something in the navigation it runs normally. The second time everything duplicates, the third triples... this continues until my browser basically needs to crash.

[image: screenshot]

I've done a bit of googling and I'm not sure if this is event propagation or event bubbling? (Very new to Javascript). I did find a similar issue on stackoverflow although I cannot submit two links.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('.loadsw').click(function() {
        $( "#loadswcontent" ).empty();
        console.log($(this).attr('href'));

        $( "#loadswcontent" ).load( "ajax/ajax-loadsw.php" + $(this).attr('href'));
        event.preventDefault();event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Full source of `ajax/ajax-loadsw.php` at http://pastebin.com/ys788rLc (Has not been refactored, it's very nasty atm).

Comment: Something to do with `ajax/ajax-loadsw.php`. Kindly show the source.

Comment: Go to the `console` tab, not the `network` one, then right-click -> log XmlHttpRequests, and refresh. Then you should see all the logs (ajax requests + console.log) which will help you debug more easily.

Comment: Hi Praveen, the full code for ajax/ajax-loadsw.php is here http://pastebin.com/ys788rLc

Comment: @bdev Er... Are you loading such a hell lot of HTML?

Comment: Yes it is meant to basically replace an entire form in a certain instance with all the values repopulated. Apologizes if this is the incorrect way to do it, I only started learning jQuery 6 hours ago... I've slept for 4 hours since then haha :)

Comment: After thinking about your comment there Praveen, I think it's better if instead of loading the entire form I set-up jQuery to target each individual element and just load the value?  Still working on the original issue though :(

Answer (score 0):

Located the answer after some digging.

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

is loading on my main-page.

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

also gets reloaded by ajax/ajax-loadsw.php

This is creating a loop as the ajax is in that script so it times its called its multiplying the events.

Lesson: don't try to learn something when you haven't slept! Thanks for everyones help.